# Server principal already exists but doesn't show in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I have created Logins in Azure SQL via SSMS on two other environments, but on the third Azure SQL Server, the same exact SQL command creates logins but they don't show in SSMS. I am using these Logins to then users for databases. As I have stated it has worked on every other Azure SQL Server.

However, when I create my Logins, they don't show up under Security > Logins and if I try to create user for the db, I get the following error:

> 'myuser' is not a valid login or you do not have permission.

Here is my SQL to create the Login:

```
CREATE LOGIN myuser WITH PASSWORD = 'p@ssword';
```

Here is my SQL I run on a selected database to add the above created user with execute rights:

```
CREATE USER [myuser] FROM LOGIN [myuser]; 
GRANT EXECUTE TO [myuser]
```

To be clear, the Login (first SQL) said that it is created, but it doesn't show in SSMS and doesn't allow me to create Users in the DBs

Comment: Contained users are not created from logins, they are CONTAINED just because they are created directly using CREATE USER command

Comment: Apologies, I meant that I am creating users as above. My primary issue is that the logins I create don't show in SSMS

Comment: Can it be DDL-trigger on the server that rolls back your CREATE LOGIN?

Comment: Does your newly created login appear in sys.sql_logins?

Comment: Very odd. After selecting the Security tab and running my script it now works. I was running against the Master for the Login creation